# How do ERC721 tokens get created on private blockchain?

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, erc-721

I'm creating a prototype using solidity for asset tracking where I need to create a new token for new items that are being added to the tracking system. I have gone through all possible tutorial on ERC721 token standard so far.

- I need a very basic sample that can explain how tokens get created.
- Can tokens be created on demand or do we have to create an initial
  set of tokens when the contract is deployed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ERC-721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) has absolutely no specifications as to how tokens should be created, other than specifying that tokens minted after contract creation must emit events following a certain pattern.

This means you're free to implement whatever token creation functions you desire.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple example that uses erc721 token?

Comment: This series will run you through how to write your own ERC721 compliant contract: https://medium.com/coinmonks/jumping-into-solidity-the-erc721-standard-part-1-e25b67fc91f3

Comment: I read somewhere that the NFTs are nothing but a link to the actual data or a hash of the complex data represented by the token. Does the token represent a value? What makes them unique?

Comment: The ERC721 standard is just for managing ownership of NFTs on the blockchain in a standardised way. The optional Metadata extension lets you add a link which points to the complex data represented by the token, but it's up to you what that points to. Two tokens can have the same metadata if you want, but they *can't* have the same `tokenId` - that's what makes them unique. As for value though - there is no inherent value in a NFT or any other crypto asset. Your NFT will only have value if it represents something people want to buy.